# Erro ao executar o método DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()

Tags: c#, app.config

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao executar a função `DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()`:

> "O sistema de configuração falhou ao inicializar"

O `app.config` está do seguinte modo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <configSections>
      <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="store" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=RL-TERMINAL\SQLEXPRESS; User ID=sa; Password=12345;Initial Catalog=store; timeout=100"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="store"/>
</configuration>
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Eu não tenho muita certeza se no lugar do `<dataConfiguration>` deveria ou não colocar a string de conexão, olha essa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993628/failing-at-database-db-databasefactory-createdatabase

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/7f2ffaac-f299-4669-81ef-ac35bc883dcb/appconfig-e-windows-service?forum=vscsharppt

Answer (score -1):

Olá. Você deve estar usando a versão 6 do EnterpriseLibrary.

Nela ocorreu uma mudança na utilização do DatabaseFactory que força a configuração inicial da Factory.

Você deve configurar o sistema assim:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" />
    </configSections>
    <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="base_de_dados" />
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="base_de_dados" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="string_conexao" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

E no seu fonte, por exemplo, basta fazer isto:

```
var factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
// Crie a base de dados desta forma.
var database = factory.CreateDefault();
using (var command = database.GetSqlStringCommand("select * from tabela"))
{
    using (var dataReader = database.ExecuteReader(command))
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
}
```